# WCF Service with existing Service/Repository Layer and EF 4.1 Code First

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I have an existing set of Services and Repositories I use in an MVC application that leverage the Entity Framework 4.1 Code First.

I want to create a couple of WCF Services that use the existing architecture, but it seems to have a hard time serializing the object graphs.

I realize that there are some circular references to deal with, but I really don't want to litter the Domain Objects with WCF attributes, so should I just create View Models like my MVC app uses? And if so, should I create the View Models to be able to be used in both?

Any other ideas? - Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer keeping my domain model and the WCF data contract separate by defining Data Transfer Object classes as the data contact of the WCF server. They are tailored specifically to carry the right data across the wire. A good DTO design will keep the number of WCF service call roundtrips from the client down. It will also separate your internal domain model from the contract with the client.

Comment: Would you consider DTO the same as View Models? Any advice on creating them so they can be used by both WCF and MVC?

Comment: It depends on what kind of MVC app you have. If it is an asp.net MVC app, then according to devdigital's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767097/is-it-feasible-to-reuse-wpf-viewmodels-in-mvc it is very much the same.